# I'm trying to send emails using sendgrid in nodejs.But am getting "TypeError: object is not a function" error

Tags: node.js

Here is my code snippet

```
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
var email     = new sendgrid.Email(); 
email.addTo('xyz@gmail.com');
email.setFrom('xyz@gmail.com');
email.setSubject('welcome to send grid');
email.setHtml('<html><body>HELLO evryone ...,</body></html>');
sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
    if(!err)
    {
        console.log("mail sent successssss");
        res.send({"status":0,"msg":"failure","result":"Mail sent successfully"});   
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("error while sending mail")
        res.send({"status":1,"msg":"failure","result":"Error while sending mail."});    
    }
});
```

Installed sendgrid throgh npm also.am getting "TypeError: object is not a function" error.MAy i know why.??

Version:--

```
sendgrid@3.0.8 node_modules\sendgrid
└── sendgrid-rest@2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using sendgrid@3.0.8 but trying to call on the sendgrid@2.* api.

v2 implementation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/nodejs.html

v3 implementation:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/nodejs.html

Give the v3 a go.

As for the type error:

v2

```
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid")("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
```

you're invoking a function

however you have v3 installed

```
require('sendgrid').SendGrid(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
```

and it's now an object

**REQUESTED UPDATE**:

I don't know too much about the keys given, but since they have tons of different supported libraries, it's completely possible that some of them use both while others use only one. If you really only have a USER_API_KEY nad PASSWORD_API_KEY, just use the user_api_key

Here is their source for the nodejs implementation module SendGrid:

```
function SendGrid (apiKey, host, globalHeaders) {
  var Client = require('sendgrid-rest').Client
  var globalRequest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('sendgrid-rest').emptyRequest));
  globalRequest.host = host || "api.sendgrid.com";
  globalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '.concat(apiKey)
  globalRequest.headers['User-Agent'] = 'sendgrid/' + package_json.version + ';nodejs'
  globalRequest.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
  if (globalHeaders) {
    for (var obj in globalHeaders) {
      for (var key in globalHeaders[obj] ) {
        globalRequest.headers[key] = globalHeaders[obj][key]
      }
    }
  }
```

The apiKey is attached to the header as an auth, and it looks like that's all you need.

Try following their install steps, without your own implementation,

**1) (OPTIONAL)** Update the development environment with your SENDGRID_API_KEY, for example:

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env

========
```

**2)** Make this class and if you did the above use process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY else put your USER_API_KEY

```
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail
from_email = new helper.Email("test@example.com")
to_email = new helper.Email("test@example.com")
subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Node.js Library!"
content = new helper.Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!")
mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

//process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY if above is done
//else just use USER_API_KEY as is
var sg = require('sendgrid').SendGrid(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
var requestBody = mail.toJSON()
var request = sg.emptyRequest()
request.method = 'POST'
request.path = '/v3/mail/send'
request.body = requestBody
sg.API(request, function (response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode)
  console.log(response.body)
  console.log(response.headers)
})
```

Comment: .......**Thanks** for response.Am new to nodejs and sendgrid.I have two api keys for sendgrid.But u mentioned like "SENDGRID_API_KEY".asssume my keys are 'xxxx','xxxxxxxx',one is API_USER AND other is  API-PASSWORD..how should i write a api for it.Please help me clearly.My work were stopped here. @Dreamlines

Comment: added more. essentially follow their docs at https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs using your API_USER key. I would also go to your account and verify you're using the right key as this nodejs implementation only needs a single API key. check under you account settings. API_USER_KEY may be the correct one still, but check anyways.

Comment: Heartly thanks again for your response.i tried like this with my keys.But i got "errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field":null,"help":null}